# Using Connection URIs with Read Replication in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

If I have a connection URI, I can use that normally with Sequelize as such:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/dbname');
```

However, if I want to use Read and Write replication (https://sequelize.org/master/manual/read-replication.html), then there doesn't seem an option to use connection URI. Can I pass connection URI strings to read and write in the replication option as in:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(null, null, null, {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  replication: {
    read: [
      'postgres://user:pass@reader.example.com:5432/dbname',
      'postgres://user:pass@anotherreader.example.com:5432/dbname'
    ],
    write: 'postgres://user:pass@writer.example.com:5432/dbname'
  }
})
```

### EDIT:

I have already found a solution to the issue. and that is using an npm library like [connection string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connection-string) to parse the connection string as shown below:

```
const write_uri = new ConnectionString(uri);
const sequelize = new Sequelize(null, null, null, {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  replication: {
    read: [
      'postgres://user:pass@reader.example.com:5432/dbname',
      'postgres://user:pass@anotherreader.example.com:5432/dbname'
    ],
    write: {
      host: write_uri.hosts[0].name,
      username: write_uri.user,
      password: write_uri.password,
      database: write_uri.path[0],
      port: write_uri.hosts[0].port
    }
  }
});
```

But, that is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per sequelize source at master, you can't.

According to the sequelize source docs at [sequelize.js](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/sequelize.js#L153), The Sequelize Constructor accepts `options` agrument, like this

```
constructor(database, username, password, options){

}
```

Where `options.replication` should be an object with two properties, read and write. Write should be an object (a single server for handling writes), and read an array of object (several servers to handle reads). Each read/write server can have the following properties: `host`, `port`, `username`, `password`, `database`.

you need to pass an array of `objects` to `read:[]` with connection values as props instead of passing `strings`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass config object to sequelize constructor even if you use uri connection.
Look the example in from the docs:
https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-constructor-constructor

> // with uri
>
> `const sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://localhost:3306/database', {})`

Look at the constructor overloading definition:

```js
Sequelize(uri: string, options?: Sequelize.Options): Sequelize.Sequelize
```

Just pass the options you need.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I've edited my question to be more precise

Comment: I can't understand your problem. Please clarify what's the wanted result.